# Slide Toggle will not stay up once clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle, slidedown, slideup

I am making a menu and have ran in to some jQuery issues.

I want my toggles to stay up once they have been clicked but instead they are sliding up but then straight back down again.

I have managed so far to have one close and another open simultaneously. Any thoughts?

Here is the current JS :

```
jQuery(".food-content").hide();
jQuery(".food-content").first().slideToggle(500);
jQuery('.food-item').click(function(){
  jQuery(".menu-container, .full-menu-container").siblings().find('.food-content').slideUp();
  jQuery(this).find('.food-content').slideDown();
});
```

I have made a JS Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/marmaaduke/uyb4Lzuy/

Answer (score 4):

Just exclude the current item clicked from the `slideUp` (with `not`) and use `slideToggle` for the current item.

```
jQuery(".food-content").hide();
jQuery(".food-content").first().slideToggle(500);
jQuery('.food-item').click(function () {
    jQuery(".menu-container, .full-menu-container").siblings().not(this).find('.food-content').slideUp();
    jQuery(this).find('.food-content').slideToggle();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/uyb4Lzuy/1/

Comment: This works perfectly on JS Fiddle, but it doesnt work on my project! I'm not sure where I am going totally wrong. http://37.61.236.221/~langtonsco/menus/

Comment: @MarmaaDuke: When it doubt, add your newly updated code to the question (or JSFiddle) and post it. Then I can spot any typos :)

Comment: Ill keep that in mind! sorry, pretty new to the forum

Comment: Run your project and save the page from the browser (e.g. use the F12 DOM inspector in Chrome). Just dump the lot into a JSFiddle and I will take a look.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean sorry, (a dev newbie).. but I have it on a test server?

http://37.61.236.221/~langtonsco/menu/

Comment: That helped. The two divs you select using `.menu-container, .full-menu-container"` are inside each other! Just change it to `.full-menu-container` and it will work. http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/wbzpb2j3/